# Combining two GROUP BY queries grouped by the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transaction table, and a tag table. I want to get a sum of all transactions in the transaction table grouped by tag. There are two different types of transaction: "budget" and "actual"

This query will return me what I want for "budget" transactions:

```
  SELECT tg.name as tag, SUM(amount) as budgetTotal 
    FROM transaction tx
    JOIN transaction_tag tt ON tt.transaction_id = tx.id
    JOIN tag tg ON tg.id = tt.tag_id
   WHERE tx.type = "budget"
     AND tx.date >= '2011-07-15' 
     AND tx.date < '2011-08-15'
GROUP BY tg.name
```

And of course pretty much the same query for "actual" transactions:

```
  SELECT tg.name as tag, SUM(amount) as actualTotal 
    FROM transaction tx
    JOIN transaction_tag tt ON tt.transaction_id = tx.id
    JOIN tag tg ON tg.id = tt.tag_id
   WHERE tx.type = "actual"
     AND tx.date >= '2011-07-15' 
     AND tx.date < '2011-08-15'
GROUP BY tg.name
```

My question: how do I group the results of these two queries, into one, so I get one results table with three columns: tag, budgetTotal and actualTotal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT tg.name, 
         CASE WHEN tx.type = "actual" THEN SUM(amount) END AS actualTotal,
         CASE WHEN tx.type = "budget" THEN SUM(amount) END AS budgetTotal
  FROM....
  WHERE  tx.type IN ("actual", "budget")
  AND   ....
  GROUP BY tg.name
```

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `SUM(CASE WHEN tx.type = "actual" THEN amount END) AS actualTotal,` and respectively for `budgetTotal` ? I mean, you shouldn't refer to `tx.type` when you use `GROUP BY` without using an aggregate (SUM in this case).

Comment: In query, if you are using sum or count or any function on the column, you have to do [group by] on all the column whatever you are 
like select a,b,c,sum(a),sum(b) from x 
group by a,b,c

Comment: @Mitch: But your answer was correct (and so was @rsbarro's) while this will show wrong results in the 2 `Total` columns. It will show (randomly) either `SUM(amount)` (over all rows and not only over "actual" or "budget") or `NULL`.

Comment: The solution that did it for me was based on this answer, and @ypercube was right...
`SELECT tg.name as tag, 
        IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN tx.type = 'budget' THEN amount END),0) AS budgetTotal, 
        IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN tx.type = 'actual' THEN amount END),0) AS actualTotal
    FROM transaction tx 
    JOIN transaction_tag tt ON tt.transaction_id = tx.id 
    JOIN tag tg ON tg.id = tt.tag_id 
    WHERE tx.date >= '2011-07-15' 
    AND tx.date < '2011-08-15' 
    GROUP BY tg.name`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tg.name as tag, SUM(amount) as budgetTotal, 'budget' as rectype
FROM transaction tx
JOIN transaction_tag tt ON tt.transaction_id = tx.id
JOIN tag tg ON tg.id = tt.tag_id
WHERE tx.type = "budget"
AND tx.date >= '2011-07-15' 
AND tx.date < '2011-08-15'
GROUP BY tg.name

UNION ALL

SELECT tg.name as tag, SUM(amount) as actualTotal, , 'actual' as rectype
FROM transaction tx
JOIN transaction_tag tt ON tt.transaction_id = tx.id
JOIN tag tg ON tg.id = tt.tag_id
WHERE tx.type = "actual"
AND tx.date >= '2011-07-15' 
AND tx.date < '2011-08-15'
GROUP BY tg.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Not dissing the other answer (which is probably better), but here's how to get it as two separate rows if that suits. Also, this answer is scalable to any number of `tx.type` without changing the query (if you remove the reference to t.type in the where clause of course):

```
SELECT tg.name as tag, tx.type, SUM(amount) as total
    FROM transaction tx
    JOIN transaction_tag tt ON tt.transaction_id = tx.id
    JOIN tag tg ON tg.id = tt.tag_id
   WHERE tx.date >= '2011-07-15' 
     AND tx.date < '2011-08-15'
     AND tx.type in ("budget", "actual")
GROUP BY tg.name, tx.type;
```

Comment: A good solution, but harder to iterate through for my purposes (JSON response to an AJAX call)